# using enum in Javascript for month number against name

Tags: javascript, enums

I need to use Javascript `enum`.

I want getting month  name for 1 or 2 or 3 ... or 12

I want to store month in numeric form and against it month name in English.

So it should be some thing like this

```
var enumMonth= {1:"Jan" , 2:"Feb", "",....,12:"Dec" }
```

So my question is how can I use enum above if I have month number `12` and I want to retrieve "Dec"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumMonth` is an Object. To access the object property value by it's key, you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
enumMonth[12]
```

to get Month Name `Dec`.

---

As the keys are sequential, you can also use array instead of object. As the array index is zero-based, need to add `undefined` on the zero'th index.

```
var months = [undefined, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
months[12];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use an object like an enum, it'd make more sense to store the month name as the key and the number as the value.

```
var month = {"Jan" : 1, "Feb" : 2, ..., "Dec" : 12};

if (monthToTest === month.Jan) {
  // do something if the month to test is January
}
```